# Canvas.textout doesn´t show text after a new series is made visible

Tags: delphi, teechart

So what i'm doing is display the x and y values of the mouse pointer on a teechart  chart using the following code, inside the onmousemove event:

```
oscilografia.Repaint;

if ((x>236) and (x<927)) and ((y>42) and (y<424)) then
begin
  oscilografia.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  oscilografia.Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
  oscilografia.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  oscilografia.Canvas.TextOut(x+10,y,datetimetostr(oscilografia.Series[0].XScreenToValue(x))+','+FormatFloat('#0.00',oscilografia.series[0].YScreenToValue(y)));
  edit1.Text:=inttostr(x)+'  '+inttostr(y);
end;
```

The code works fine, but a problem happens when i make another series visible by selecting it on the legend: the text inside the box created by canvas.textout isn´t shown anymore.

The box is still there following the mouse, but without any text. So i would like a solution to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic problem is down to how painting works. Windows do not have persistent drawing surfaces. What you paint onto a window will be overwritten the next time the system needs to repaint it.

You need to arrange that all painting is in response to `WM_PAINT` messages. In Delphi terms that typically means that you would put your painting code in an overridden `Paint` method.

So the basic process goes like this:

1. Derive a sub-class of the chart control and in that class override `Paint`. Call the inherited `Paint` method and then execute your code to display the desired text.
2. In your `OnMouseMove` event handler, if you detect that the mouse coordinates text needs to be updated, call `Invalidate` on the chart.
3. The call to `Invalidate` will mark that window as being dirty and when the next paint cycle occurs, your code in `Paint` will be executed.
4. What is more, when anything else occurs that forces a paint cycle, for instance other modifications to the chart, your paint code will execute again.

Note, as an alternative to sub-classing, you can probably use the `TChart` event `OnAfterDraw`. But I'm not an expert on `TChart`, so am not sure. The main points though are as I state above.

Comment: But the thing is that the box where the text is located appears, but the text don´t. And the box and text are paint with the Canvas.TextOut function. I followed the code from this tutorial: http://www.steema.com/support/teechart/6/tutorials/hintsoverline/

Comment: The tutorial you followed has clearly given you bad advice for the reasons outlined in my answer. How much do you understand about Windows painting and `WM_PAINT`?

Comment: Nothing. But how can you explain the fact that the code only stop working after i make a new series visible on the legend?

Comment: Because that forced a paint cycle. Don't you think you ought to learn about `WM_PAINT` and how painting works in Windows?

Comment: I would assume the same should happen if you were to minimize your form and restore it again, or even drag another window over top of it.

Comment: David Hefferman is absolutely right in his approach. In the original the line oscilografia.Repaint; is a bit of a cheat. It tricks Windows into thinking that it is not necessary to redraw the canvas so the text that the mouse draws on it does not get lost. It is very bad practice. If you added that line to the end of your routine the text would never appear.

Answer (score 1):

From [a comment you wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350270/canvas-textout-doesn%C2%B4t-show-text-after-a-new-series-is-made-visible#comment48794658_30350474), I see you followed [this example](http://www.steema.com/support/teechart/6/tutorials/hintsoverline/).
Note it doesn't draw any rectangle; it only draws text, so I'm not sure to understand what box is following your mouse.
Also note the example calls `Invalidate`, as [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30350474/509369).
Find below a modified version of the same example, painting a rectangle before the text.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Series1.FillSampleValues(10);
    Chart1.View3D := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.Chart1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
Y: Integer);
var tmpL,tmpL2,ClickedValue : Integer;
    tmpWidth, tmpHeight: Integer;
    tmpText: string;
begin
    clickedvalue := -1;
    tmpL2:= -1;

    With Chart1 do
    begin
        If (Series1.Clicked(X, Y) <> -1) And (not OnSeriesPoint) Then
        begin
            Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
            Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
            Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
            tmpText:=FormatFloat('#.00',Series1.XScreenToValue(x))+','+FormatFloat('#.00',Series1.YScreenToValue(y));
            tmpWidth:=Canvas.TextWidth(tmpText)+10;
            tmpHeight:=Canvas.TextHeight(tmpText);
            Canvas.Rectangle(x+5, y, x+tmpWidth, y+tmpHeight);
            Canvas.TextOut(x+10,y,tmpText);
            OnSeriesPoint := True;
            ClickedValue:= Series1.Clicked(x,y);
        End;

        //Repaint Chart to clear Textoutputted Mark
        If (ClickedValue=-1) And (OnSeriesPoint) Then
        begin
            OnSeriesPoint := False;
            Invalidate;
        End;

        tmpL := Chart1.Legend.Clicked(X, Y);

        If (tmpL <> -1) And ((tmpL <> tmpL2) Or (not OnLegendPoint)) Then
        begin
            repaint;
            Canvas.Brush.Color := Series1.LegendItemColor(tmpL);
            Canvas.Rectangle( X, Y, X + 20, Y + 20);
            Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
            Canvas.TextOut(x+15,y+7,FormatFloat('#.00',Series1.XValues.Items[Series1.LegendToValueIndex(tmpl)]));
            tmpL2 := tmpL;
            OnLegendPoint := True;
        End;

        If (tmpL2 = -1) And (OnLegendPoint) Then
        begin
            OnLegendPoint := False;
            Invalidate;
        End;
    End;
End;
```

Comment: What happens when a paint cycle comes along?

Comment: The chart is repainted, not the text. Another solution would be using OnAfterDraw to draw the text. Both the text and the position could be stored in a global variable at OnMouseMove.

Comment: That's the entire point of the question then isn't it. You've just repeated the mistake made by the code in the question.

Comment: Sorry I was trying to get the minimal code to reproduce the issue. Your answer is the good one (and I voted for it). I just wondered what is @gabriel doing to get that box following his mouse without text.

Comment: Btw, you ought to mention (perhaps in your user name), that you are a Steema dev. That would be useful knowledge for people that you are helping here.